# How to skip a message matching a certain pattern if it repeats more often than a limit?

Tags: rsyslog, filter

Is it possible to `stop` a matching message if it appears more frequently than a given limit? I'd like to achieve something like this:

```
if $programname == "foo" and
   $msg contains "bar" then {
  action(type="continue" action.execonlyonceeveryinterval="7200")
  & stop
}
# Further processing of messages.
```

Except that there is apparently no such `continue` or no-op action.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. You can only filter based on the content of the logs.

But you can execute a script, by using the [omprog module](https://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/modules/omprog.html). The script could then check the amount of times a message has been received.

```
module(load="omprog")

if $msg contains "bar" then {
    action(type="omprog" binary="/path/to/script.py --param1=\"some param value\"")
}
```